# UIElement.setIcon() Does Not Work in E4

Tags: eclipse-plugin, e4

On my never-ending quest to fix the bugs introduced with E4 I now stumbled over a very blatant bug:

```
public class MyHandler extends AbstractHandler implements IElementUpdater {

    @Override
    public void updateElement(UIElement element, Map parameters) {
        Image image = // find my image
        element.setIcon(ImageDescriptor.createFromImage(image));
    }

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that `MenuHelper.getIconURI(ImageDescriptor, IEclipseContext)` gets called somewhere down the road and of course an `ImageDescriptor` created from an Image doesn't have a URL of any kind.

Is there any way to assign a URL? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem so I tried out all the possibilities and it turned out that the following line can solve the problem:

```
element.setIcon(ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(Activator.getDefault().getBundle().
        getEntry("imagepath")));
```

Comment: Thank you. Problem is: we don't have an URL. We painted the image in question ourself.